# 16.04.1 LTS server drops wifi connection when ethernet disconnects (NUC6i5SYH)

Tags: wireless, network-manager, headless

**tldr:** headless server connected via ethernet on one IP and wireless on another. live ssh sessions on each. Pull the ethernet cable, the wireless gets torn down along with it.

**Details:**

Setting up a new NUC6i5SYH as a headless media server. It's not important to me for this thing to connect to wifi, but I wandered down the path of headless wifi management for the education of it all.

Fresh NUC box, built-in WIFI left unconfigured during the initial BIOS setup. While connected via ethernet, installed network-manager and nmcli, 
and got a wifi connection up and going:

```
sudo nmcli device wifi connect <ssid> password XXXXX
```

(this cmd had to be repeated a few times with varying errors but eventually succeeded and stuck)

ssh to the wireless ip. pull the ethernet cable. both connections get torn down. router tells me wired and wireless MAC are not connected, no IP addresses for either.

It's repeatable: connect ether, wireless comes up with it, disconnect ether, wireless disconnects with it.

On a reboot with no ethernet cable, wireless comes up and connects like a champ. (but now plugging in the ethernet cable does not get IP, seems that's a different issue).

What's up with the wifi behavior on ether disconnect?

Comment: That would be a bug, but I never experienced this behavior. Look at the log file of NetworkManager to understand why wifi disconnects. Possibly enabling debug logging first by configuring logging. level=TRACE in NetworkManager.conf.

Comment: haven't dropped this, just have not had a chance to collect the suggested logs.